# @CompileStatic using config script with dependencies

Tags: groovy

Using a Groovy compiler config script, it is possible to add CompileStatic AST Transformation to every classes of a package and its subpackages within the project.

Is it possible to do the same with dependencies classes at runtime?

Comment: Could you be more specific as of what "dependencies" means here?  That would only work for `.groovy` files, that are not yet compiled.

Comment: The dependency is a java library that only works as expected if I wrap it's object inside a method and use @CompileStatic on it. I'm trying to find a better solution

Comment: Please add an minimal example, that show the problem.

Comment: Sure. Consider this reproducer https://github.com/ptomaszek/vertx-groovy

The class MainGroovy should print true, but it prints false. To make it print true you have to add @CompileStatic to the class or to the main method. I would like to find an alternative solution

Comment: Isn't this due to the missing parens around println?

Comment: No, parens aren't mandatory in Groovy